# concatenate/ Join string onto itself X number of times based on column value separated by the character "|" (pipe)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a puzzle where I have one amount value(string) listed in a "rate" column.  Working with the rate column, I need to multiply the rate times the "nights" column and separate each rate value(string) with a "|"pipe character.  There will never be a need for the pipe character at the 1st or last position.

Any help that you can provide to get me moving forward I would appreciate it.

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd


data = [['CZK', '125.45', 1], ['CZK', '1726',3], ['CZK', '135',2], 
['CZK','2152.33',3]]


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['currency', 'rate','nights'])

#--------------- 

data2 = [['CZK', '125.45',1], ['CZK', '1726|1726|1726',3], ['CZK', 
'135|135',2],['CZK','2152.33|2152.33|2152.33',3]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['currency', 'rate','nights'])

#---------------

df['pipecount'] = (df['nights'] - 1)    # Gets the number of PIPEs needed  "|"


#df['Rate'] = ['|'.join(s[i:]) for i, s in zip(df['pipecount'], df['Daily 
Rate'].str.split('|'))]


#df = df.drop(['pipecount'], axis=1)


print("Before")
print(df)
print('\n')
print("After")
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string manipulation:

```
df['rate'] = df['rate'].astype(str).add('|').mul(df['nights']).str.strip('|')
print(df)

# Output
  currency                     rate  nights
0      CZK                   125.45       1
1      CZK           1726|1726|1726       3
2      CZK                  135|135       2
3      CZK  2152.33|2152.33|2152.33       3
```

Details:

```
steps = pd.concat([
    out := df['rate'].astype(str).add('|'),
    out := out.mul(df['nights']),
    out := out.str.strip('|')
], axis=1, keys=['step1', 'step2', 'step3'])
print(steps)

# Output
      step1                     step2                    step3
0   125.45|                   125.45|                   125.45
1     1726|           1726|1726|1726|           1726|1726|1726
2      135|                  135|135|                  135|135
3  2152.33|  2152.33|2152.33|2152.33|  2152.33|2152.33|2152.33
```

Comment: Note, you can remove `astype(str)` if `rate` is already a string (like your example) but you need this cast if `rate` is a real number.

Comment: This is absolutely amazing. It work like a charm.  This currency CZK column data was filtered out of a larger spreadsheet with multiple different type currencies. Could I apply your code after a filter for CZK and get the same results?  Something like this df.loc[(df['currency'] == 'CZK). this apply your code at this point.     My reasoning would be not have the need to filter for all CZK and separate the data, apply your fix and then copy it back into the main spreadsheet.   You have given me a great start and I appreciate your time.  Thank You.

Comment: Also Thanks for the Details.  It explains a  lot!!

Comment: What you could use: `df['rate'] = df['rate'].mask(df['currency'] == 'CZK', other=df['rate'].astype(str).add('|').mul(df['nights']).str.strip('|'))`. Let me know if this is what you expect?

Comment: Wow Wow Wow.....The first snippet you had would remove currency string if not CZK and replace with NaN. everything else worked.   Your second snippet just now worked perfect!!  Did not remove or replace other currency types.....PERFECT!!  Thank you so much..   have a good rest of your day.